# how to read mapped data from firestore in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read mapped data from Firestore. I am reading data but I do not know how to reach one of the keys in the map.

[this is mapped data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srCjt.png)

```
dbSaveAvailableTimes.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                val chaplainAvailableTimes = snapshot.data
                if (chaplainAvailableTimes != null) {
                    Log.d("chaplainAvailableTimes", chaplainAvailableTimes.toString())
                }
```

I read the data here.

D/chaplainAvailableTimes: {1637868400000={patientUid=null, isBooked=false, time=1637868400000}, 1637863200000={patientUid=null, isBooked=false, time=1637863200000}}

I get results like this in the log.

when I try the  `chaplainAvailableTimes["time"]`, I get null.

So, how can I take the time key data after that? I am not familiar with the map in Kotlin. thanks for your help in advance?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: hi, I added the screenshot. if you click "this is mapped data", you will see the database structure. thanks

Comment: So to understand better, you want to read the value of "time" that exists under each object, right?

Comment: @kadiryapar Do you want a list of these `time`s as there are many of them OR just the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my last question:

> So to understand better, you want to read the value of "time" that exists under each object, right?

And your last answer:

> hi, yes. thanks

To get the values of "time" from within each object, please use the following lines of code:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val availableTimesRef = db.collection("chaplainTimes").document("availableTimes")
availableTimesRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        val data = it.result.data
        data?.let {
            for ((key, value) in data) {
                val v = value as Map<*, *>
                val time = v["time"]
                Log.d(TAG, "$key -> $time")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
1637863200000 -> 1637863200000
1637868400000 -> 1637868400000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of `time`s using this code:

```kotlin
// This will be a List<String>
val timeList = snapshot.data.values.map { (it as Map<*, *>)["time"] as String }
```

- `snapshot.data` returns the MutableMap<String,Any>
- `.values` returns the collection of map values `Collection<Any>`
- `.map` transforms each value to get a `List<String>`
- inside `map` we cast each value to a generic map `Map<*,*>`, fetch the value for key `time` and cast it to a `String`

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast `chaplainAvailableTimes` as `val theData = chaplainAvailableTimes as? HashMap<*, *>`. After that you will be able to iterate over it or get the data like this:

```
theData.values.first().get("time") // returns 1637868400000
```

Comment: hello, I tried it but it still returns null. Also, there is no option .first[ ]. What do you mean with that. thanks

Comment: Try to force cast it (`as`, without `?`) and post the error message here. If cast is successful, the result should be map. Map has .values.first property which returns first element (same as values.[0]).  I've updated the code for map (was for array before, sorry).

Comment: hello, 'theData.values.first()' method is available but 'theData.values.first["time"]' this one is not available. 'theData.values.first()' this method return the first element of the array which is {patientUid=null, isBooked=false, time=1637868400000}. I want to reach time key under every object. thanks for your support.

Comment: I've updated the code to get time. Check the main answer.

Comment: hi, if you mean the update "theData.values.first()["time"]" this code, it is not working. after the first() method, it does not accept ["time"] .

Comment: how about theData.values.first().get("time")?

Comment: hi, no. there is no .get( ) method. When I tried  for (k in theData){
                    val result = theData.values
                    Log.d("theData $k", result.toString())
                } , I get the {patientUid=null, isBooked=false, time=1637868400000} this result in every for loop. But I do not know how to reach time inside it